# The operator == is undefined for the arguments type bool

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, boolean

Could anyone help me with that? I get the error stated with the following code:

```
  if (actualStep.getChanged() == null) {
        notificationCombo.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("There are no new changes."));
        notification.setImage(notificationBLUE);
    }
```

I get a Nullpointer when compiling as the boolean is not inizalized.

Comment: boolean have a default value, are talking about `boolean primitive` or `Boolean object` ?

Comment: I suspect that your object actualStep is null. Can you verify that it has been initiated?

Comment: ‘*Nullpointer when compiling*’?! Is this a question about a compilation error or a runtime exception?

Comment: What is `actualStep`? What does `getChanged()` return? How should we know?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For questions about exceptions please post (1) [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), (2) a full stack trace formatted as code and (3) which line in your code the stacktrace refers to. This will *greatly* improve our chances of helping you. Also, I don’t see any Boolean variable in your code. Was I supposed to?